# Valores por defecto en FullCalendar Drag&Drop

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy haciendo un calendario para turnos (elementos) que son arrastrados desde un panel lateral (se selecciona un cliente) hacia el `full calendar`.
Una vez que el evento se encuentra en el full calendar, se pueden realizar con él tres acciones:

- Mover: Podes arrastrarlo a otra fecha o a otro horario
- Modificar duracion: si seleccionas la parte de abajo del evento, te deja agrandar o achicar, para darle otro horario de finalizacion
- Ver datos: Al hacer click le configuré un modal que meuestra datos

El `elemento turno` se crea mediante la siguiente funcion

```
  $('#add-new-event').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
            //Get value and make sure it is not null
        var val = $('#new-event').val()
        if (val.length == 0) {
            return
        }

        var desc = $('#new-desc-event').val()
        console.log(desc);
        //Create events
        var event = $('<div />')

        event.css({
            'font-weight': 300,
            'background-color': currColor,
            'border-color': currColor,
            'color': '#fff'
        }).addClass('external-event')
        if (desc == "") {

            event.html(val)
        } else {

            event.html(val + ' - ' + desc)
        }
```

Una vez creado el elemento (Que contiene el nombre de un cliente y una descripcion), yo puedo selccionarlo y arrastrarlo hacia el calendario, que tiene la siguiente configuracion

```
new FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable(containerEl, {
    itemSelector: '.external-event',
    eventData: function(eventEl) {

        return {
            title: eventEl.innerText,
            backgroundColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
            borderColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
            textColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('color'),
        };
    }
});

view = 'timeGridDay';
header = {
    left: 'prev,next timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth',
    center: '',
    right: ''
};


var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'local',
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
    defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
    defaultDate: hoy,
    header: header,
    businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
        {
            daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            startTime: '09:00', // 8am
            endTime: '21:00' // 6pm
        }
    ],
    minTime: "09:00",
    maxTime: "21:00",
    events: [{
        title: 'Agustin Guerra',
        start: '2020-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2020-03-12T11:30:00',
        description: 'hola'
    }],
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        e = JSON.stringify(calEvent.event.end)
        s = JSON.stringify(calEvent.event.start)

        //  Configurando StartDate
        var startObj = (calEvent.event.start);
        var local = startObj, // Local timestamp
            m = new moment(local), // Moment representing local time
            a = moment.utc(local), // Specify that 'local' is UTC
            b = m.utc(+3); // Generate UTC time from local
        start = m.format();


        //  Configurando EndDate
        var startObj = (calEvent.event.end);
        var local = startObj, // Local timestamp
            m = new moment(local), // Moment representing local time
            a = moment.utc(local), // Specify that 'local' is UTC
            b = m.utc(+3); // Generate UTC time from local
        end = m.format();

        dia = (end).substr(8, 2);
        mes = (end).substr(5, 2);
        ano = (end).substr(0, 4);
        fecha = dia + '-' + mes + '-' + ano;


        $("#title").val(calEvent.event.title);
        $("#date").val('El dia ' + fecha);
        $("#start").val('Desde las ' + (start).substr(11, 5));
        $("#end").val('Hasta las ' + (end).substr(11, 5));
        $("#description").val(calEvent.event.description);


        $("#exampleModal").modal();

    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function(info) {

        info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);

    }
});
```

Como pueden ver, la propiedad `events` tiene un evento estático que le cargue a modo de ejemplo.

```
events: [{
            title: 'Agustin Guerra',
            start: '2020-03-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2020-03-12T11:30:00',
            description: 'hola'
        }]
```

> Lo que sucede es lo siguiente: Al clickear sobre un evento que ya se encuentra en el calendario, se abre un modal donde se pueden ver los siguientes datos: Nombre del cliente, Fecha del turno, Hora de inicio, Hora de fin, y Descripcion. Pero tengo un error en esta parte.

Si yo arrastro el evento desde el panel lateral al calendario, y luego le doy click al mismo (ya en el calendario) el modal se abre pero no tiene la `Fecha` ni la `Hora de finalizacion`, pero sí tiene el `Cliente`, la `Hora de inicio` y la `descripcion`.

Si al evento lo arrastro y lo cambio de fecha o de hora de inicio, el problema continua.

Si al evento le modifico la duracion, ahora se configura bien y el modal muestra los datos correctamente.

Yo quisiera que al arrastrar el evento por primera vez se carguen correctamente la fecha y la hora de finalizacion.

Comment: Nada? =( me tendré que ir a SO en ingles a ver que pasa

Answer (score 0):

El problema se solucionó estableciendo la siguiente propiedad en la declaración del calendario:

```
forceEventDuration: true
```